# Disable edit on a field depending on a Picklist value in Apex

Tags: apex

Hi I need your help here.

We need to have **schedule.Start_Date__c** disabled when **schedule.Products_Offer__c == 'Product B'.**

Also, I would like to know if it is possible that it will be disabled as soon as I select the Picklist *Product B*.

```
<apex:actionRegion>
<div class="slds-truncate" title="">
    <apex:inputField style="width:90px;" value="{!schedule.Start_Date__c}" rendered="{!schedule.Products_Offer__c != 'Product B'}">
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="tableId" status="status"/>
    </apex:inputField>
    <apex:outputField style="width:90px;" value="{!schedule.Start_Date__c}" rendered="{!schedule.Products_Offer__c == 'Product B'}">
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="tableId" status="status"/>
    </apex:outputField>
</div>
</apex:actionRegion>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a few solutions to render the VF Page Upon changing the picklist Value/other input fields.
 (a) use 'html-disabled' under your inputField tag.

```
html-disable="{!IF((schedule.Products_Offer__c == 'Product B'), true, false)}"
```

(b) Use render and rerender tag for instant changes. Like reRender="name of block to be rendered"  and rendered="your condition".

```
<!--Sample-->
<apex:actionRegion>
  <apex:inputField value="{!schedule.Products_Offer__c}">
     <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="disableField" /> 
   </apex:inputField>
</apex:actionRegion>
<apex:outputPanel id="disableField">
   <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!schedule.Product_Offer__c=='Product B'}">
     <apex:outputField value="{!schedule.Start_Date__c}" /> 
   </apex:pageBlockSection>
 </apex:outputPanel>
```

Also, we can use these two options. The overall logic will be the same.

(c) Use JS to render the pages Upon changing the field value and Last but not least

(d) Use Apex Class to fetch condition

I hope this resolves your problem.

Thanks,
Sourav Saha